# the maximum of several right continuous stepfunctions are also right continuous

Tags: functions, measure-theory, calculus

I want to proof that in general the maximum (or minimum) of several right continuous step functions are also right continuous. For example, consider $g_1$, $g_2$ and $g_3$ defined as follows:
$  g_1 (x)  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & 0 \le x < 0.5 \\
       0.5 & 0.5 \le x < 1 \\
     1 & x \ge 1 \\
 \end{array} 
\right. $; 
$  g_2 (x)  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & 0 \le x < 0.25 \\
       0.25 & 0.25 \le x < 1 \\
     1 & x \ge 1 \\
 \end{array} 
\right. $ and 
$  g_3 (x)  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & 0 \le x < 0.6 \\
       0.6 & 0.6 \le x < 1 \\
     1 & x \ge 1.
 \end{array} 
\right. $

Define $f(x)=max\{g_1(x), g_2(x), g_3(x) \}$, $\forall x \in [0, \infty].$
How to approach a general proof. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_1,\ldots, g_n\colon I\to \Bbb R$ be right continuous step functions and $f\colon \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ an *arbitrary* function. Then $F(x):=f(g_1(x),\ldots, g_n(x))$ defines a right continuous step function $F\colon I\to \Bbb R$.

We need to show that for all $x\in I$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $F$ is constant on $[x,x+\epsilon)$.
So let $x\in I$ be given. For each $i$, we know that there exists $\epsilon_i>0$ such that $g_i|_{[x,x+\epsilon_i)}$ is constant. Let $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n\}$. Then all $g_i$ are constant on $[x,x+\epsilon)$, henec so is $F$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\max$ function is continuous, hence if $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$ are right-continuous we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to c^+}\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)\}
&=\max\{\lim_{x\to c^+}f_1(x),\lim_{x\to c^+}f_2(x),\lim_{x\to c^+}f_3(x)\}\\
&=\max\{f_1(c),f_2(c),f_3(c)\}
\end{align}

which implies that $g(x)=\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)\}$ is itself right-continuous.